# How can I filter an array based on a category in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ramda.js

I'm learning React and trying to figure out how I can filter an array based on categories.

The data I'm working with is something like this here: 
http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c2bd5683000006900abaff9

So I'm able to filter out all of the categories using this:

```
getTheCats() {
    const cats = [...new Set(this.getVehicleData().map(v => v.category))];
    const catsR = cats.filter(c => c).map((category, i) => {
        // console.log(this.props.vehicle);

        return (
            <Col
                xs="12"
                key={i}
                onClick={() => this.getCategories(category)}
                className={
                    this.state.category === category
                        ? 'border-bottom p-15 active'
                        : 'border-bottom p-15 not-active'
                }
            >
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={this.state.active ? faMinusCircle : faPlusCircle}
                />
                <h5 className=""> {category} </h5>
                <SpecsDetails
                    key={this.props.vehicle.id}
                    vehicle={this.props.vehicle}
                />
            </Col>
        );
    });
    return (
        <Row className="deal-details__specs accoridon-heading" id="specs">
            {catsR}
        </Row>
    );
}
```

This gives me all of my individual categories. But what I need to do now is get all of these into an accordion. So the category is actually the heading of the accordion. How can I get all of the data that matches each category?

Comment: The code sample looks truncated; it's not clear how you compute `catsR`.

Comment: In case you're interested, here's an alternative to using `Set` to compute a unique list of categories: `const categories = compose(uniq, map(prop('category')))`.

Comment: I apologize. Yes it was truncated..catsR just returns the rest of of my component and then I render it out.  I've updated the question with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` to get an object of categories, with an array of values for each category. You can then convert it to an array of category onbjects, using `toPairs` and `map` with `zipObject`:

```js
const { pipe, groupBy, prop, toPairs, map, zipObj, dissoc } = R;

const groupByCategories = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('category')),
  map(map(dissoc('category'))), // optional - if you want to remove the category from the values
  toPairs,
  map(zipObj(['category', 'values']))
)

const data = [{"label":"Remote trunk/hatch release","category":"Comfort & Convenience","value":"Remote control trunk/hatch release"},{"label":"Cruise control","category":"Comfort & Convenience","value":"Included"},{"label":"Cargo area light","category":"Comfort & Convenience","value":"Included"},{"label":"Computer","category":"Comfort & Convenience","value":"Trip computer: includes average fuel economy and range for remaining fuel"},{"label":"Headlight control","category":"Comfort & Convenience","value":"Headlight control with dusk sensor"},{"label":"Power locks","category":"Comfort & Convenience","value":"Card key power locks ; automatic locking"},{"label":"Ventilation system","category":"Comfort & Convenience","value":"Ventilation system with micro filter"},{"label":"Secondary ventilation controls","category":"Comfort & Convenience","value":"Passenger ventilation controls"},{"label":"Air conditioning","category":"Comfort & Convenience","value":"Dual-zone climate control"},{"label":"Power windows","category":"Comfort & Convenience","value":"Front windows with one-touch on two windows, rear windows"},{"label":"Spare wheel","category":"Comfort & Convenience","value":"Included"},{"label":"Compass","category":"Comfort & Convenience","value":"Included"},{"label":"Smart card / smart key","category":"Comfort & Convenience","value":"Keyless Enter ‘n Go™ smart card/smart key with keyless entry"},{"label":"Vehicle start button","category":"Comfort & Convenience","value":"Included"},{"label":"External","category":"Dimensions","value":"L: 189.8, W: 76.5 - H: 69.3"},{"label":"Cargo area dimensions","category":"Dimensions","value":"Cargo area dimensions: loading floor height (inches): 32.4"},{"label":"Weight","category":"Dimensions","value":"6,500 (lbs)"},{"label":"Engine","category":"Engine","value":"3.6 v6 V"},{"label":"Fuel system","category":"Engine","value":"Multi-point fuel injection"},{"label":"Fuel Type","category":"Engine","value":"unleaded"}]

const result = groupByCategories(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I did, except that I included `map(map(dissoc('category'))),` before `toPairs` to remove the repetitive data.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - Thanks. I thought about it, but since the data is used for rendering in React, I'm not sure if it's that critical. I'll it as an option. Happy new year :)

Comment: I tend to like to do this everywhere, even when it's not really necessary, to make the structures I use further down the line more understandable.  But there definitely is a strong case for not doing so here.

Comment: This worked great! Thank you.Can you provide any tutorials or examples for Ramda? I found the ones on their website a little hard to follow for a first timer like myself.

Comment: Welcome. I liked this [course](https://egghead.io/playlists/learn-ramda-js-ec318ad7), and I'm sure @ScottSauyet knows about more resources.

Comment: Christopher Okhravi talks extensively about Ramda functions on his Youtube channel: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbF-4yQQAWw-UnuCd2Azfzg/videos --> he goes by the functions 1 by 1.

Comment: I really like Randy Coulman's [Thinking in Ramda](http://randycoulman.com/blog/categories/thinking-in-ramda/) series.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually get this done with some object tricks

```
let categories = {};
this.getVehicleData().map(vehicle => { 
  categories[vehicle.category] = categories[vehicle.category] || []
  categories[vehicle.category].push(vehicle)
})
```

You can access the values by

```
Object.keys(categories).map(category => {
  console.log('category', category)
  console.log('values', categories[category])
})
```

Hope this works :)